# OpenGL-based library

Tags: c++, library, opengl

I've been working, for a month, on an OpenGL library called alpha++. Basically, it is a framework that allows the user to create 3D scenes easily.

I would like to ask your advice on how I could make the user interface simpler. Here is the way I use my classes at the moment in Main.cpp:

Main.cpp

```
///  _______ _       _______         _______    _       _
/// (  ___  ( \     (  ____ |\     /(  ___  )  ( )     ( )
/// | (   ) | (     | (    )| )   ( | (   ) |  | |     | |
/// | (___) | |     | (____)| (___) | (___) |__| |__ __| |__
/// |  ___  | |     |  _____|  ___  |  ___  (__   __(__   __)
/// | (   ) | |     | (     | (   ) | (   ) |  | |     | |
/// | )   ( | (____/| )     | )   ( | )   ( |  | |     | |
/// |/     \(_______|/      |/     \|/     \|  (_)     (_)

/*
    PLEASE IGNORE : this is a test file for the alpha++ library !
*/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include "utility.h"
#include "Shader.h"
#include "Window.h"
#include "Vertex.h"
#include "Mesh.h"
#include "Texture.h"
#include "Material.h"
#include "Transform.h"
#include "camera.h"
#include "ModelLoader.h"

#define WIDTH 1000.0
#define HEIGHT 900.0
#define FPS 120

using namespace alpha;

static volatile bool isRunning = false;

struct PhongLight{
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 intensities; /// color of light
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Window window(300, 100, WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Oppa Win - e dooooow !", true);

    ///managing textures
    Material material;
    material.AddTexture("grid_metal", new Texture("res/Metal4.jpg", GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LINEAR));
    material.AddTexture("modern_metal", new Texture("res/Metal5.jpg", GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LINEAR));

    Mesh mesh("res/Test.obj");

    ///Shaders...
    Shader shader;
    shader.loadFromFile(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "res/basicShader.glslv");
    shader.loadFromFile(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "res/phongShader.glslf");
    shader.CreateAndLink();

    shader.Bind();
        shader.RegisterAttribute("position");
        shader.RegisterAttribute("texCoord");
        shader.RegisterAttribute("normal");
        glBindAttribLocation(shader.GetProgramID(), shader.GetAttribLocation("position"), "position");
        glBindAttribLocation(shader.GetProgramID(), shader.GetAttribLocation("texCoord"), "texCoord");
        glBindAttribLocation(shader.GetProgramID(), shader.GetAttribLocation("normal"), "normal");
        shader.RegisterUniform("modelView");
        shader.RegisterUniform("MVP");
        shader.RegisterUniform("time");
        shader.RegisterUniform("lightPosition");
        shader.RegisterUniform("lightIntensities");
        ///shader.RegisterUniform("lightDirection"); used for basic Fragment Shader
    shader.UnBind();

    Camera camera(glm::vec3(0, 0, -4), 70.0f, (float)window.GetWidth() / (float)window.GetHeight(), 0.01, 1000.0f);
    Transform transform;

    /// ///////////////////UNIFORMS //////////////////////// //
    glm::mat4 modelView;
    glm::mat4 projectionView;
    glm::mat4 modelViewProjection;
    glm::vec3 lightDirection = glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    glm::vec2 screenResolution = glm::vec2(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    PhongLight phongLight;
    phongLight.position = glm::vec3(4.0, 4.0, -4.0);
    phongLight.intensities = glm::vec3(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);

    ///LOOP REALTED THINGS
    float delta = 0.0f;
    isRunning = true;
    unsigned frameRate = 1000 / FPS;
    Uint32 atStart = 0, atEnd = 0, elapsed = 0;

    while (isRunning)
    {
        atStart = SDL_GetTicks();
        window.Clear(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        ///Updates
        transform.GetRot() = glm::vec3(.0, delta * 500, .0);

        modelView = transform.GetModelView();
        projectionView = camera.GetViewProjection();
        modelViewProjection =  projectionView * modelView;

        ///Rendering
        shader.Bind();
            material.GetTexture("grid_metal")->Bind(0);
                glUniformMatrix4fv(shader.GetUniformLocation("MVP"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelViewProjection));
                modelView = glm::mat4(1);///Light point doe not move !
                glUniformMatrix4fv(shader.GetUniformLocation("modelView"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelView));
                glUniform1f(shader.GetUniformLocation("time"), delta);
                ///glUniform3fv(shader.GetUniformLocation("lightDirection"), 1, glm::value_ptr(lightDirection));
               /// used for the basic fragment shader !
                glUniform3fv(shader.GetUniformLocation("lightPosition"), 1, glm::value_ptr(phongLight.position));
                glUniform3fv(shader.GetUniformLocation("lightIntensities"), 1, glm::value_ptr(phongLight.intensities));

            mesh.Draw();
        shader.UnBind();

        delta  += 0.002;

        window.SwapBuffers();
        window.Update();

        isRunning = !window.isCloseRequested();

        ///FPS COUNT
        atEnd = SDL_GetTicks();
        elapsed = atEnd - atStart;

        ///SLEEP
        if(elapsed < frameRate)
            SDL_Delay(frameRate - elapsed);

    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;///YEHE ! EVERYTHING WENT RIGHT !

}
```

Comment: You are misusing the `volatile` qualifier. Read about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437527/why-do-we-use-volatile-keyword-in-c).

Comment: Yes, I know ! But my main loop is not finished yet, and I want to run the main loop on a seperate thread ( like in java ) !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Note: I'll probably be using some C++11 and C++14 features, so if you can't use such features, just ignore them.*

#### No raw `new`.

```
material.AddTexture("grid_metal", new Texture("res/Metal4.jpg", GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LINEAR));
```

There is no need to use raw `new` here.
Either refactor your `Texture` class to contain a pointer to some `TextureImpl` class,
or use C++14 `std::make_unique` to create a `std::unique_ptr`.

For example:

```
material.AddTexture("grid_metal", std::make_unique<Texture>("res/Metal4.jpg", GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_LINEAR));
```

#### Use RAII (or something) for shader binding.

First, why unbind the shader at all?
You can't draw anything without a shader,
and binding a shader automatically unbinds the old shader,
so I see no need for call to `shader.UnBind()`.

But, if you want to guarantee the shader gets unbound, I'd have the library make the guarantee, not the user.

One way would be to pass a function to some `Shader::UseWith` method that guarantees a call to `UnBind`.

Example using C++11 lambdas:

```
void Shader::UseWith(std::function<void()> func) {
    this->Bind();
    func();
    this->UnBind();
}

// inside main()
{
    shader.UseWith([&]{
        shader.RegisterAttribute("position");
        // etc.
    });
}
```

#### What purpose do `RegisterAttribute` and `RegisterUniform` serve?

I assume you're using `glGetAttribLocation` and `glGetUniformLocation`,
and storing the results in some `std::map<std::string, GLuint>`?

This is a needless burden on the user of your interface.

Right after you link your shader, you can use `glGetActiveAttrib` and `glGetActiveUniform` to enumerate all of your attributes and uniforms.
This would allow you to "register" everything for the shader all in one place.

Making this change would allow you to just remove all calls to `RegisterUniform`, with no other changes to the interface.

Another issue with `RegisterX` is that the user could mistakenly call these methods twice with the same parameter.
What happens if the user calls `shader.RegisterAttribute("position")` twice?

#### Encapsulate `glUniform*` and `glBindAttribLocation`

What's the point of wrapping shader programs in `Shader` if all it does is compile them and cache uniform locations?

`Shader` should provide some overloaded methods or method templates to mirror these functions.

Either of these could work:

```
shader.SetUniform("time", delta);
shader.Uniform("time").Set(delta);
```

#### Hide the main loop

Things such as framerate counters, sleeping, and buffer swapping should be hidden behind the interface.

A good way to do this is move the whole main loop into the library, and have it call a user function.

Example:

```
void Window::MainLoop(std::function<void(float)> userFunc)
{
    ///LOOP REALTED THINGS
    float delta = 0.0f;
    bool isRunning = true;
    unsigned frameRate = 1000 / FPS;
    Uint32 atStart = 0, atEnd = 0, elapsed = 0;

    while (isRunning)
    {
        atStart = SDL_GetTicks();
        Clear(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

        userFunc(delta); // HERE //

        delta  += 0.002;

        window.SwapBuffers();
        window.Update();

        isRunning = !window.isCloseRequested();

        ///FPS COUNT
        atEnd = SDL_GetTicks();
        elapsed = atEnd - atStart;

        ///SLEEP
        if(elapsed < frameRate)
            SDL_Delay(frameRate - elapsed);
    }
}

// inside main()
{
    window.MainLoop([&](float delta)
    {
        ///Updates
        transform.GetRot() = glm::vec3(.0, delta * 500, .0);

        modelView = transform.GetModelView();
        projectionView = camera.GetViewProjection();
        modelViewProjection =  projectionView * modelView;

        ///Rendering
        shader.Bind();
            // etc.
        shader.UnBind();
    });
}
```

#### Getters shouldn't return mutable references.

```
transform.GetRot() = glm::vec3(.0, delta * 500, .0);
```

For what purpose? Why not just expose `transform.rotation` (or whatever it's called)?

If you want to encapsulate it with methods,
then `GetRot()` should return a `const glm::vec3&`,
and there should be a `SetRot(const glm::vec3&)` method to match it.

#### Other nitpicks

- Don't use #define for constants in C++. `static const` works fine, or `constexpr` in C++11.
- Why is `isRunning` volatile and global? That sounds like a bad idea.
- The name `Material` seems weird. I would expect something like `TextureManager`.
- `#include <cstdlib>` instead of `#include <stdlib.h>`
- Most of your headers are `UpperCase`, but `"utility.h"` and `"camera.h"` aren't.
- Why is `frameRate` an `unsigned`? Just make it an `int`. Shouldn't it be a `double` anyway?

#### Refactoring `GetUniformLocation`

To help with removing the need for `RegisterUniform`, I would refactor `GetUniformLocation` to look something like this:

```
GLuint Shader::GetUniformLocation(const char* name) {
    auto iter = uniforms.find(name);
    if (iter == uniforms.end()) {
        GLuint loc = glGetUniformLocation(/* program */, name);
        if ( loc == -1 ) {
            std::clog << "Warning: Uniform " << name << " is inactive!" << std::endl;
        }
        iter = uniforms.insert({name, loc}).first;
    }
    return iter->second;
}
```

Comment: 1) Never mind about C++11 and 14 : I use C++11 features very frequently !

Comment: 2) if the user calls register twice, an ALPHA_REGISTERED_TWICE exception is thrown !

Comment: 4) Register actually gives the user the guarantee that the uniforms exists : if they do not, an ALPHA_UNIFORM_NOT_FOUND exception gets thrown !

Comment: 5) Should I then encapsulate glUniform and glAttribute into two diff. structures ? Then there would be a method which retrn that structure, and I can update it !

Comment: 3) I know : i just hacked things together for the main loop ! I know that my loop is really really bad : for instance, the updates a relative to the FPS count !

Comment: @MattMatt Regarding "4) Register actually gives the user the guarantee that the uniforms exists," what do you do when uniforms do not exist because they are totally optimized out? Inactive uniforms appear as if they never existed (`glGetUniformLocation` returns `-1`, and `glUniform*(-1,...)` has no effect and is not an error).

Comment: So you say I should not store my uniform locations in a map, but just use glGetUniformLocation() ?

Comment: @MattMatt You should definitely store the locations somewhere, since calling `glGetUniformLocation` can be inefficient. What I meant was that you shouldn't treat missing uniforms as an error. If `glGetUniformLocation` returns `-1`, then just store `-1` as the location in the map, and maybe print out a warning to the console.

Comment: OK, so I should remove the RegisterX() method, and  keep the GetUniformLocation method. If the method would face an attribute not registered yet, it would register it; and if the value of that uniform would be -1, I would throw an exception and the program would go on ? So the method would look like this :                                                                                             `GLuint GetUniformLocation(const char* name){                                            if( uniforms.find(name) ==  uniforms.end() ) /* here we register the unif */     else return uniforms[name] } `

Comment: @MattMatt Yes, but I wouldn't throw an exception. A uniform location of -1 is not an error. *Edit: I added a code snippet to the end of my answer.*

Comment: 1) Thanks ! but you talked about glGetActiveUniforms : how should I call it after linking the program ?

Comment: 2) The main reason I used Register was for performance : won't it count itering in a map for performance  ( maybe i can use hashtables ? ) ?

Comment: 3) I guess it's the same thing for getting attrib locations...

Comment: @MattMatt Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24879/discussion-between-alchemicalapples-and-mattmatt).